# Using URL's in print_r()

Tags: php

My `img.php` file allow you to view images, but the site reduces the size of image. The php file uses `?id=` to get file name and echo out correct image, however I want the user to be able click the image and be redirected to the full image.

`print_r($_GET['id']);` allows me to print the filename, but I also need to link the directory somewhere in there, I tried using this - `print_r($dir($_GET['id']));` but that didn't work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think a little bit more explanation is needed to help you here. If you want to redirect used, based on click, then hyperlinks are your friend.

Comment: I understand, I'm not very experienced with php so it's a bit hard to explain, basically I want to echo out a hyperlink in php so the link would be "website.com/images/123.jpg" instead of "website.com/123.jpg"

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, `img.php?id=lion` will show a small lion image, and if you click on that image, you want to go to `website.com/images/lion.jpg`? Have I got it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

if($id){
$id = htmlentities($id);
echo "<a href='website.php/image/$id.jpg'>"; echo "<img src='images/$id.jpg'> </a>";
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I realize I tried this earlier but wrote "" instead of '' inside the href.

Comment: There's no point checking if $id is empty if you're going to allow `''` anyway. Also, this needs htmlspecialchars or it is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: I didn't use the entire script, I only looked for the url part :)

Answer (score 1):

`print_r` should be used only to print out an array in a human readable format (for debugging). Perhaps you want to do something like:

```
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']) . '"><img src="' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']) . '"/></a>';
```